# Woocommerce: Interaction with Payment Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

EDIT:
Hi, so what I have is a fully functional shop. I need to add a third party API call after payment is processed, it would work like this:

```
AUTH Payment Gateway
IF YES then call Third Party API to add customer information
    IF YES CAPTURE the Payment
        CALL Third Party API to ADD Transaction Information and Response from Gateway 
    IF NO VOID the Payment
IF NO proceed with normal Payment Gateway Plugin behavior
```

Any ideas which would be the best way to achieve that? Where do I add those calls to the Third Party API? Thanks

Comment: Why is this better than creating a payment gateway that integrates with WooCommerce? But, almost everything is possible with enough time.

Comment: Hi @helgatheviking you are right, I don't think this would be the best solution for my problem. I'm posting another question that will make more sense. Thanks

Comment: @helgathevikin I edit the question, I believe now it describes better the problem. I hope you can help! Thanks!!!

Comment: Yes, the question now is basically "how do I create a payment gateway?" I've never made one myself, but I'd start by looking at how WooCommerce does it's built-in gateways.... for example [PayPal Standard](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/gateways/paypal/class-wc-gateway-paypal.php). Start with a [gateway plugin base](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/payment-gateway-api/) and read the [gateway api docs](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/payment-gateway-api/). There appears to be plenty of info on Google.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. We already have the payment gateway plugin installed. I just need to add the calls to the third party API based on the flow described at the question... that's what I'm having problems with.

Answer (score -1):

Can I suggest you to ask that question again over at https://facebook.com/groups/woohelp and tag a guy by the name of "Luke Cavanagh​"

He'll should still have the whole setup.